# Copying a directory in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 6.  I know how to copy and move files.  I also know how to move a directory like this:

```
        //create variables for names of old and new storage directories
    $source = 'plan_submission/'.$currentPlanSubmissionId. '';
    $destination = 'plan_submission/'.$newPlanSubmissionId. '';

    //replicate the old directory into the new directory
    Storage::move($source, $destination);
```

However, I cannot figure out a way to copy a directory into a new location.  I would imagine there is a simple way to do this with something like 'Storage::copy' but do not see that in Laravel documentation.  My only other thought is to create the new directory, copy all directories, and put those copies into the new directory.  That seems very inefficient though.

Answer (score 2):

use Laravel's File [copyDirectory](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_copyDirectory) helper

```
\File::copyDirectory($source, $destination);
```

Comment: may be because of the folder permission. which os are you using, make sure  your php has write access to the path

Comment: I'm using XAMPP for Windows.  I have lots of places in the application where I am writing folders to storage that work fine.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

*config/filesystems.php*

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],
    ...
]
```

Copy all files from *public/seed_images/* to *public/images/*

*app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php*

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$fromFiles = Storage::allFiles('seed_images');

for ($i=0; $i < count($fromFiles) ; $i++) {
    $toFile = str_replace("seed_images","images",$fromFiles[$i]);
    Storage::copy( $fromFiles[$i], $toFile );
}
```